# Determining the color name or hexidecimal in R from default factor colors scheme

Tags: r, colors, default

I made a plot with the first three colors defaulted in the factor() (pink, green, and blue colors)

```
dat = data.frame(x=rnorm(9,0,1),y=rnorm(9,0,1),z=rep(1:3, times = 3))
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(z)), shape = 20, size=5)
```

Is there a way I could determine what the color string name or hexadecimal value is for the first x colors returned by the default when factor() is used?

Comment: For example: `plot(1:3, 1:3, pch=20, col=scales::hue_pal()(3), cex=5)`

Comment: There may be a more direct way of finding this out, but if your `ggplot` object is named `p`, then `ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]` should give you the hexadecimal color codes used in the plot.

Comment: @nrussell That's also included in the duplicate of the duplicate ;)